# Simple HTML Dom PHP

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

help me please...

image -> [my result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mLLwO.jpg)

my testing result, i don't know why?

```
price("http://www.example.com/"); -> work
price("http://www.example2.com/"); -> not work
```

try switch line.

```
price("http://www.example2.com/"); -> work
price("http://www.example.com/"); -> not work
```

Here's my script...

```
<?php
include_once('simple_html_dom.php');

function price($url){
  $html = file_get_html($url);

  foreach($html->find('span[class=col-right]') as $li){
       echo $li->innertext;
  }
}

price("http://www.example.com/");
price("http://www.example2.com/");
?>
```

Comment: well I just hit the URL http://www.google.com/test1 , test2 and google returns 404

Comment: Indeed, thats not a valid page

Comment: my url  suppose for example

Comment: "not work"  is nothing happened

Comment: Does the second page have any class=col-right element? Try echoing the parsed $html tree. The problem seems to be data-related.

Comment: Try to start with price("http://www.example2.com/");     -> work
price("http://www.example.com/"); ->not work

Answer (score -1):

Due to php5 circular references memory leak, after creating DOM object, you must call $dom->clear() to free memory if call file_get_dom() more then once.

Example:

```
$html = file_get_html(...); 
// do something... 
$html->clear(); 
unset($html);
```

Comment: i try added nothing happened.